# Error when saving data in admin user interface in django

Tags: python, django

When I enter data into the admin interface to an app in Django using sqlite3 database I got this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/

no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

Comment: have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate whenevr you do changes on django models.